# Como Concatenar los parametros de un reporte hecho en reporting services dentro del select

Tags: sql

Tengo dos parametros:

@p_month @p_year y tengo que concatenarolo mas un constante dentro del select

Esto es permitido o está bien?

Select @p_month + p_year + "00" as perido, campo2, campo3,...campo n FROM TABLA

Esperando una respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: Qué motor estás utilizando? La respuesta puede ser diferente para cada uno de ellos.  Lo intentaste? Qué respuesta obtuviste? Cual era la respuesta esperada? Llevas siete meses en el sitio, Pablo. Ya debes saber [como realizar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Está permitido siempre que el tipo de dato sea consistente, en el peor de los casos:  `Select convert(varchar,@p_month) + convert(varchar,@p_year) + "00" as perido, campo2, campo3,...campo n FROM TABLA`

Comment: Gracias Patricio.

Comment: No te precupes Ariel. Hay un foro para consultar. Y gracias por la correción